# Theoretical analysis of STL decomposition

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, decomposition

I would like to know if, for some specific models, the STL ("seasonal-trend decomposition using LOESS, see [here](https://www.wessa.net/download/stl.pdf)) algorithm for time series analysis is proved to converge (in some sense).

For example, if $N = kn$ for two non-zero integers $k,n$, if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, and if $(e_j)_{j \in \{0,\cdots, N-1\}}$ is a i.i.d. sequence of gaussian variables, let us define $\forall j \in \{0,\cdots,N-1\}$, $y_j := a\cdot j + b\cdot e^{i\frac{jk}{N}} + \epsilon_j$.

Then $(y_j)_{j \in \{0,\cdots,N_1\}}$ is a random time series. Can one prove that there is a choice of parameters of the STL algorithm that almost surely outputs $j \mapsto a\cdot j$ as the trend component and $j \mapsto b\cdot e^{i\frac{jk}{N}}$ as the seasonal component? Or, maybe just, in a loose sense, that the trend and seasonal components are close to these ones?

Comment: Can you please expand STL? And, do it as an edit to the post, not as a comment!

Comment: Done. I thought this was a well-known algorithm, but if you don't know it, it is probably not.